# How to round off the specific range value via excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, rounding

I need to round off the range("M2:M13") value to two decimal points.I wrote the below code using "NumberFormat" option but **when I copy paste this value to another workbook it displays me the whole number in formula bar and the rounded off number in the selected cell**.

How do I completely round off the numbers to two decimal points?

```
Sub RoundOff()
    Worksheets("Sheets2").Activate
    Range("M2").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat="0.00"   
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1="RC[-3]/RC[-4]*100"
    Range("M2:M13").Select
    Selection.FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Use Round Function? Like `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1="=ROUND(RC[-3]/RC[-4]*100,2)"`

Comment: No words to appreciate your assistance.Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Nilusha M. It s missing one "=" before "RC[-3]/" from your formula.

You can try:

```
Sub Test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("M2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-3]/RC[-4]*100"
        With .Range("M2:M13")
            .FillDown
            .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked as I expected.Thank you for the assistance

Comment: @NilushaM. Glad to hear that my answer is useful. In order to help more people with the same issue please void the answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by simply doing
`range("A1").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#.00"`

It will format the entire A column